# Enabling SSL for a subdomain in IIS

Tags: iis, ssl, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I recently bought SSL for my website and want to create a section within the site in the form of https://secure.example.com/member/upgrade.aspx. However, I am having a hard time solving this issue since currently my website URL rewrite prohibits any subdomain and the user is logged out if he or she gets transferred to the above link.

I have search online and found some good information such as dynamically create the url without actually creating a subdomain in IIS.

**Questions**:

1. What steps are needed to achieve the objective above?
2. Should I have bought the wildcard certificate instead of one for a specific subdomain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be ignoring that url pattern for rewrite purposes or ignoring the url if the protocol is HTTPS. That said, I would take a slightly different approach here and just put the entire site behind SSL -- rewriting all the queries to the other protocol works and [google is now giving rankings bumps to HTTPS](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html) so there are good business reasons to make the switch. You are already taking the pain of getting SSL involved at all -- the dedicated IP and certficate cost the same if you use them on a single page or all the pages, might as well take advantage of it and ease your management burden in the same motion.